# Why does cancelling my running akka quickstart example app throw a java error?

Tags: scala, akka

When I hit control-C to cancel my running akka quickstart app I get the following error.
Is this normal or is there an akka config that can avoid this?

Can someone explain why this occurs?

```
sbt:akka-quickstart-scala> exit
[info] shutting down sbt server
[warn] Run canceled.
Exception in thread "sbt-bg-threads-1" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.externalSubmit(ForkJoinPool.java:2328)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.externalPush(ForkJoinPool.java:2419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.execute(ForkJoinPool.java:2648)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:24)
    at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool$BackgroundRunnable.$anonfun$cleanup$1(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:390)
    at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool$BackgroundRunnable.$anonfun$cleanup$1$adapted(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool$BackgroundRunnable.cleanup(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:389)
    at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool$BackgroundRunnable.run(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:359)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is the version of sbt that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue that can be seen in this [github issue link](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5226).

In my case, When I upgraded my sbt to 1.3.3, same issue cropped up, my akka code was not getting closed using `CTRL+C` when launched by `sbt run`. It only logs a warning message and does not stop. So, I had to downgrade the sbt version from `1.3.3` to `1.2.8` to make it work.

Please let me know if it helps!!